# convert image url into bitmap its showing out of memory error sometimes while using in marker

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm using Map in my application so I'm customising the marker in my map. When application opens if I give image url directly its not displaying so I'm converting into bitmap.
sometimes application getting crashes. I referred many links but I didn't get proper code.

Issues:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   Failed to allocate a 55987212 byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(BitmapFactory.java)

code:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("http://default-environment.8ed3pmbznb.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/images/profile/2018-04-03-14-01-022017-11-13-07-12-36Image.jpg");
            Bitmap  bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
         Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapimage, 100, 100, true);
           //scaled = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ServerUtils.Gs_ImagePath+gs_var_user_image);

        }

        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Setting image in marker:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawableToIcon(getContext(),scaled, Is_active)));
        mMap.addMarker(mMarker);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
```

customizing marker in layout

```
public  Bitmap drawableToIcon(@NonNull Context context, Bitmap image, String status) {


    View marker = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);

    ImageView rlay = (ImageView) marker.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    markerImage.setImageBitmap(image);

    marker.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    marker.layout(0, 0, marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight());
    marker.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable drawable = marker.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    marker.draw(canvas);

    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

If I set the image url directly into marker, first time is not loading, when refresh page only showing that'y I converting as bitmap. Even though i reduced the bitmap size also using this

```
createScaledBitmap(bitmapimage, 100, 100, true);
```

Anyone can reply me please

Answer (score 1):

> Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapimage, 100, 100, true);

That is the wrong approach as before you create that big bitmap `bimapimage' that already caused the oom.

Instead you should use `decodeStream` with a scale options parameter so you will directly get a small bitmap.